# Jquery readmore function not working correctly

Tags: jquery

### Code

```
 var showChar = 50;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Read More";
    var lesstext = "Less";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if (content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar - 1 , content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">' + ellipsestext + '</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }

    });
```

For the above code suppose the readmore link is as shown below.

```
"Lorem Ipsum has been the standard dummy text ever since th...[Read more]"
```

Then when I click on readmore instead of showing the paragraph like this

> Lorem Ipsum has been the standard dummy text ever since **the**
>   1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it
>   to make a type specimen book.

Its showing like this

> Lorem Ipsum has been the standard dummy text ever since **th he**
>   1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it
>   to make a type specimen book.

### JSFiddle

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52wj8mym/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updated jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/52wj8mym/4/)

**2 Changes:**

In the following statement, remove the first `&nbsp;` because it is adding an unnecessary space.

```
var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">' + ellipsestext + '</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
```

And, replace `showChar - 1` by `showChar` in the following, because it is taking the last letter in the shorter text as well.

```
var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var h = content.substr(showChar , content.length - showChar); // 'showChar-1' -->showChar

var html =....</span>&nbsp;<span..... //remove &nbsp;
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/52wj8mym/3/

Answer (score 0):

try using `showChar` instead of `showChar-1`:

```
var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
```